# Finding missing word and displaying It

Tags: excel

I need to know some programming code to solve the following conditions:

1. I had some ten names in Sheet1 and nine names in Sheet2.
2. How to write the code to search which name is missing in Sheet2 when compared to sheet1 and display the missing name in Sheet2 after comparing with Sheet1?

I tried:

```
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim EID(1 To 5) As Integer
For i = 1 To 5
EID(i) = Range("A" & i).Value
Next i

For i = 1 To 5
If Not ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(EID(i)) Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Missing Number is" & EID(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

If both lists are labelled and sorted in ColumnA, then in B2 of Sheet2 copied down to suit:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Sheet1!A$2:A$11,A$2:A$10,0)),"",INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$11,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A$2:A$11,0)-1))
```